# Is it possible to change the default notification Alert Style upon application install?

Tags: ios

When I install my app then go to the notification section of settings, the Alert Style is set to Banner.
Is this an iOS wide setting and the same for all apps, or is there some setting in info.plist for example that can enable the alerts style to be of type Alert rather than of type Banner upon installation?

Comment: interesting idea, but i guess that's not configurable. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but the answer is no. You have just a little influence on the presentation of the notification. Setting the presentation style is then up to the user and you can't modify it at any point.

see:
[related stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229385/set-default-ios-local-notification-style-for-application)

Answer (score 0):

I've yet to see an application display a custom push notification beyond the blue banner. It would lead me to believe that it is currently not configurable.

Comment: Its not about customizing it, its about setting the *default* type.