# iPhone - Can we tell if notification style is set to 'Banner' or 'Alerts'

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can an application tell if the notification style is set to 'Banner' or 'Alerts'? I know you can check 'None' because Apple provides `UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone`. But what about others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as seen in these two questions:

1. [Is it possible to change the default notification Alert Style upon application install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591636/is-it-possible-to-change-the-default-notification-alert-style-upon-application-i?rq=1)
2. [Set default iOS local notification style for application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229385/set-default-ios-local-notification-style-for-application).