# IOS get Property of Local Notification

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

Is it possible to ask the user to select notification type "alerts" by presenting them an option at install.  Similar to how we ask users to enable location services some thing like that.

i.e i need current "**notification style**" to check whether it is banner or alert type ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do this since Apple hasn't exposed any methods to change the banner types.

You can read up on following post for possible solutions,

[Set default iOS local notification style for application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229385/set-default-ios-local-notification-style-for-application)